# Why segmentation fault is occurring in following code

Tags: c

This program tries to create separate linked list for each line of input. The first line contains the number of testcases and the following lines contain the space separated integers as link list elements.

Sample input:

```
2
1 2 4 6
3 9 11 12
```

Expected Output :

```
LinkList 1 : 1 2 4 6
LinkList 2 : 3 9 11 12
```

This function puts each space-separated integer line into a string and passes it to the `makelist` function

```
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d\n",&t);   //number of testcases
    int x;

    while(t--)
    {
        struct node *head1=NULL,*head2=NULL;

        int i=0,j,k;
        int len1=0,len2=0;
        char str1[200],str2[200];

        fgets(str1,200,stdin);   //input first line
        fgets(str2,200,stdin);   // input second line

        len1=strlen(str1);
        len2=strlen(str2);

        printf("length,of strings %d %d",len1,len2);
        makeList(str1,&head1,len1);    //fault occurs here
        makeList(str2,&head2,len2);
    }
}

//program to make linklist from input string
void makeList(char *str,struct node ** head,int len)
{
    printf("Inside makelist");
    int i ;
    struct node *temp, *temp2;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if((str[i]>=48 )&& (str[i]<=57))   // converting string to integer
        {
            printf("NUmber found");
            temp=makeNode();
            temp->val=str[i];
            temp->next=NULL;

            if(*head==NULL)
                *head=temp;
            else
            {  
                temp2=*head;
                while(temp2->next!=NULL)
                    temp2=temp2->next;
                temp2->next=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printList(*head);
}

//program for allocating memory for new node 
struct node *makeNode()

{
    struct node *newNode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    return newNode;
}
```

Comment: `struct node *MakeNode()`?

Comment: Did you use a debugger?

Comment: Where inside of `makeList` did the fault occur?

Comment: Use the debugger to step into `makeList(str1,&head1,len1);` and post which line the fault occurs.

Comment: when calling scanf() (and family of functions), always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   When calling malloc() (and family of functions), 1) in C, do not cast the returned value.  it is already a void* which can be assigned to any pointer.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc() to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling the user function: makenode(), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the function was successful.  Before exiting main(), all the malloc'd memory area pointers need to be passed to free().  Strongly suggest only processing one line at a time.  Since no 'new' 'head' memory pointers are declared, if the input were greater than 2 then data would be overwritten.

Comment: The posted code is missing key elements like: which header files, definition of struct node, prototypes for user functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use 2 for two lines of input and then do `fgets()` twice per loop, you need to decrement twice. This `t--` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

in the following (untested) code,

I had to make some guesses about what you actually want the program to perform.

the following code:

```
compiles cleanly, 
performs appropriate error checking,
cleans up after itself,
etc.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node *next;
};

// prototypes
void makeList(char *str, int whichList);
struct node *makeNode( void );
void printList( struct node *head);

static struct node **listOfNodes = NULL;

int main( void )
{
    int t;
    if( 1 != scanf("%d\n",&t) )   //number of testcases
    {// then scanf failed
        perror( "scanf for number of test cases failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    if( NULL == (listOfNodes = malloc( t* sizeof(struct node) ) ) )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc failed for list of nodes");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    // clear listOfNodes to make cleanup easier
    memset( listOfNodes, 0x00, t*sizeof(struct node) );

    for( int i = 0; i<t; i++ )
    {
        char str1[200];

        fgets(str1,200,stdin);   //input line
        makeList(str1, i);
    } // end for

    // cleanup
    for(int i=0; i<t;i++)
    {
        struct node *myNode = listOfNodes[i]; // get linked list ptr
        while( myNode )
        {
            free(myNode);
            myNode = myNode->next;
        }
    } // end for

    free( listOfNodes );
    return 0;
} // end function: main


//program to make linklist from input string
void makeList(char *str, int whichList)
{
    printf("Inside makelist");
    int i =0;
    struct node *temp, *temp2;

    char *token = strtok( str, " "); // setup for first number

    while( token )
    { // then number found
        printf("NUmber found\n");
        if( NULL == (temp=makeNode() ) )
        { // then makeNode failed
            return;
        }

        // implied else, makeNode successful

        temp->val=atoi(&str[i]);
        temp->next=NULL;

        if(NULL == listOfNodes[whichList])
            listOfNodes[whichList]=temp;
        else
        {
            temp2=listOfNodes[whichList];
            while(temp2->next!=NULL)
                temp2=temp2->next;
            temp2->next=temp;
        }

        token = strtok( NULL, " "); // setup for next number
    }
    printList( listOfNodes[whichList]);
} // end function: makeList


//program for allocating memory for new node
struct node *makeNode()
{
    struct node *newNode=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    return newNode;
} // end function: makeNode
```

Comment: `listOfNodes = malloc( t* sizeof(struct node) )` --> `listOfNodes = malloc( t* sizeof(struct node*) )` , `temp->val=atoi(&str[i]);` --> `temp->val=atoi(token);`

Comment: `free(myNode);  myNode = myNode->next;` is wrong. (`myNode->next` : `myNode` already `free`'d.)